# how to change the author variable in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

this question is related to PyCharm.

how do i change the value in the variable

```
__author__ = 'my login name'
```

it takes my shell user variable. can i change it in my preference anywhere?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Open Settings | File Templates and change the text of "File Header" template to use your full name instead of ${USER}.

Comment: PyCharm | Preferences | File Templates (for Mac OS)

Comment: PyCharm | File | Settings | IDE Settings | File and Code Templates | Python Script / Python Unit Test

Comment: Since PyCharm 4.0, it is now. File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates. Then change the **Python Script** template.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same problem as you, and found the best answer to it here:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html#d600783e347

You can't just change exisitng variables, but you can create your own ones. I encourage you to use this solution, instead of replacing the variable by your full name. Sooner or later you will run in the situation, that you need it in more than one file template and in that moment it will become a fun killer to rechange your name in each template.

TL;DR
Goto `Settings | File Templates` switch to `Includes` tab, create a new file and type e.g. `#set( $MyName = "John Smith" )`. Then go to your template in the `Templates` tab and add to the template on the top `#parse ("your-include-name.your-extension")` Now you can use `$MyName` in this template.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming this is on Windows environment and the Pycharm is installed under path:

`X:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm x.x.x\`

editing

`X:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm x.x.x\bin\pycharm.exe.vmoptions`

adding line:

```
-Duser.name=MyName<myemail@mycompany.com>
```

restart PyCharm

Comment: same approach is applicable to other JetBrains products like PhpStorm, RubyMine and so on..

Answer (score 6):

Settings (or Default Settings) >> Editor >> File and Code Templates >> File type (e.g.: Python Script)

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you showed here. However, it does not work after restarting Pycharm..

Answer (score 3):

I found a probable solution from [JetBrains's help website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-template-variables.html?keymap=primary_default_for_windows).

> Besides predefined template variables, it is possible to specify custom variables. 
>   If necessary, you can define the values of custom variables right in the template using the `#set` directive.
>
> For example, if you want to use your full name instead of your login name defined through the predefined variable `${USER}`, use the following construct:
>
> ```
> #set( $MyName = "John Smith" )
> ```
>
> If the value of a variable is not defined in the template, PyCharm will ask you to specify it when the template is applied.

**Here is my demo:** `(PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1 x64)`

1. Go to `Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes`

   - Press `+` to create a new template.
   - For me, I name the `Name:` to 'Header', `Extension:` to 'py'
   - I set my name to `$USER` and put it before the text I want to show. [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCQjc.png)

     ```
     #set($USER = "Roy WAN")
     # Created by $USER at ${TIME} ${DATE} using ${PRODUCT_NAME}
     ```
2. Go to `Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Files`

   - Now we can copy the following code into the file templates we need.  [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsRIT.png) [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaaDm.png)

     ```
     #parse ("Header.py")
     ```

     The output is like this. [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS0YH.png)

     ```
     # Created by Roy WAN at 16:36 29/12/2019 using PyCharm
     ```

P.s. Be careful not to put after the text. [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EiuG.png)

```
    # Created by $USER at ${TIME} ${DATE} using ${PRODUCT_NAME}
    #set($USER = "Roy WAN")
```

Otherwise, it will still print out default `${USER}`. [`<screenshot>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQIpt.png)

```
    # Created by 11848 at 16:46 29/12/2019 using PyCharm
```

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 4.0 on a Mac - PyCharm | Preferences | | Editor | File and Code Templates

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Template
In that Choose the language for which you want to change the name
Write your name instead of ${USER}